# Customizing enumerate \item numbers

Tags: lists, enumitem

I need to enumerate a nested list of items with two counters, so that consecutive items have numbers like 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, then 2-1, 2-2, 2-3, 2-7, then 4-1, 4-3, 4-5, and so on.

The two tricky parts are that I need to be able to control...

1. where the second counter rolls over (i.e. going from 1-4 to 2-1 in the example above), and
2. where each counter has an increment greater than 1 (i.e. going from 2-3 to 2-7, or from 4-1 to 4-3 to 4-5, in the example above).

(My document is a solution manual for a book whose problems are numbered this way, but I don't yet have solutions for every one -- so I need to jump the numbers in some spots. But I would very much like to avoid numbering `\item`s manually, since that would defeat the purpose of `enumerate`.)

**Edit** Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*--\arabic*]
\item 1--1: This is easy.
\item 1--2: This is mostly easy but there's a twist.
\item 1--3: This is hard.
\item 2--1: This is very hard. % Step "major" number (1-->2).
\item 2--5: This is nearly impossible. % Discontinuous step in "minor" number (1-->5).
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Instead of the desired problem numbers, this produces 1--1, 2--2, 3--3, etc.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With `enumitem` and custom counters you are in the right direction, but please help us help you by providing a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, you are expected to provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: @TeXnician, Sandy G - Sorry about the omission. MWE added above. And two folks have already posted perfect, if non-obvious (to me at least) responses. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a similar approach except that I override `\item` so that you can use it to change the problem counters. For example,

```
\item[3-2]
```

will set the current item number to `3-2` after which `\item` will produce `3-3`, `3-4`, ... until the next `\item` with an optional argument.

I have used the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package
to wrap the code into a new `problems` environment, which also means that you can use all of the usual `enumitem` formatting etc. For an extended example,

```
\begin{problems}[nosep]
  \item bla
  \item bla
  \item bla
  \item[1-8] bla
  \item bla
  \item[2-1] bla
  \item bla
  \item[2-4] bla
  \item bla
  \item[3-2] bla
  \item bla
\end{problems}
```

will produce

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\let\realItem\item
\newcounter{problem}
    \setcounter{problem}{1}
\newcounter{subproblem}[problem]
\renewcommand\thesubproblem{\arabic{problem}-\arabic{subproblem}}

\def\SetProblemCounters#1-#2!!{% extract new problem and subproblem numbers
  \setcounter{problem}{#1}
  \setcounter{subproblem}{\numexpr#2-1\relax}% so that \ref will work properly
}
\newcommand\myItem[1][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\SetProblemCounters#1!!\fi%
   \refstepcounter{subproblem}%
   \realItem[\thesubproblem]%
}

\newlist{problems}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[problems]{before=\let\item\myItem}
\begin{document}

\begin{problems}[nosep]
  \item bla
  \item bla
  \item bla
  \item[1-8] bla
  \item bla
  \item[2-1] bla
  \item bla
  \item[2-4] bla
  \item bla
  \item[3-2] bla
  \item bla
\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

**Some explanation of the code**

- The macro `\SetProblemCounters` is defined by `\def\SetProblemCounters#1-#2!!`. What this means is that it expects two arguments where `#1` is what appears between `\SetProblemCounters`  and a`-` and `#2` is what appears between the `-` and `!!`. If you try to use it without following this syntax an error error results. The only reason why `-` and `!!` are part of the definition of `\SetProblemCounters` is to give an easy way to extract the value of `problem` and `subproblem`. As explained below, this is achieved using `\myItem`. (You could use anything you want instead of `!!`, provided you also change the `!!` in `\myItem`.)
- The `before=\let\item\myItem` inside the `\setlist{...}` for the `problems` environment says that when you are inside a `problems` environment then `\item` is really the macro `\myItem`
- By definition `\myItem` takes an optional argument, which by default is empty. The line `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` is the "standard way" to check to see if `#1` is empty. When it is non-empty, then `\myItem` "gives" `#1!!` to `\SetProblemCounters` -- in particular, note that it adds two exclamation marks!! So, inside the `problems` environment, if you type `\item[3-7]` then this becomes `\myItem[3-7]` and then `\SetProblemCounters3-7!!`. Consequently, `\SetProblemCounters` ends up with `#1` equal to `3` and `#2` equal to `7`. (If you type `\item[2]` inside a `problems` environment then you will get an error because `\SetProblemCounters` expects to find a `-`.)
- What `\SetProblemCounters` actually does is set the `problem` counter equal to `#1` and the `subproblem` counter equal to `#2-1`, which is does using `\numexpr` (the `\relax` tells `\numexpr` where to stop). The `\myItem` macro always increments the the `subproblem` counter, using `\refstepcounter{subproblem}`, with the result that `\label{...}` and `\ref{...}` will now have the expected values.
- Finally, the line `\let\realItem\item` makes a "copy" of the original `\item` command. This lets `\myItem` use the "real" item, via `\realItem[\thesubproblem]`, because when `\myItem` is being used the macro `\item` *is actually equal to* `\myItem`.

Comment: This is (also) exactly what I was looking for, but there's a fair bit going on in your code that I'll need to study carefully. One thing I don't understand is the syntax of the `SetProblemCounters` definition -- It looks like it expects two numerical arguments separated by a dash, but when invoked in the `myItem` block that follows, there's only a single argument (`#1`). Also, what's the meaning of the double exclamation point? (That feature is particularly hard to Google ...).

Comment: @Jim I'll add some more explanation

Comment: @jim I have also changed the code a little so that it now defines and uses `\thesubproblem`. I realised that this was necessary in order have `\label{...}` and `\ref{...} work as advertised.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

[image]

Use `\stepcounter` or `\refstepcounter` to increment `outernum`; use `\stepcounter`, `\refstepcounter`, or `\addtocounter{innernum}{<n>}` to increment `innernum`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%% Define two new counters
\newcounter{outernum}
\newcounter{innernum}[outernum]

%% Create a custom enumerated environment
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{compenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[compenum]{label=\arabic{outernum}-\arabic{innernum}}

%% Modify behavior of \item inside 'compenum' env.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{compenum}{%
  \let\origitem\item
  \renewcommand\item{\refstepcounter{innernum}\origitem}}

\begin{document}

\begin{compenum}
\stepcounter{outernum}
\item bla
\item bla
\item bla
\item bla

\stepcounter{outernum}
\item bla
\item bla
\item bla
\addtocounter{innernum}{3}
\item bla

\stepcounter{outernum}
\stepcounter{outernum}
\item bla
\addtocounter{innernum}{1}
\item bla
\addtocounter{innernum}{1}
\item bla
\end{compenum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I had already tried `\stepcounter`, but neglected to define inner and outer counters explicitly. Nice!

Comment: Rather than use `\AtBeginEnvironment` you can use`\setlist[compenum]{before=...}` to run some code at the start of your `compenum` environment.

Comment: @Andrew -Is the `\AtBeginEnvironment` route somehow problematic?